# Jedis pool configuration for get and set/flush operations

Tags: redis, jedis

I am new to redis and  using Jedis client in my application. I have gone through couple of threads and did not find the conclusive answers.

I have 2 questions where I need clarity.

1. For my production use I want to set separate timeout for jedis get operations and set operations. For all set operation I want to set timeout to 2000ms and for get 100ms. I have implemented below configuration.

   ```
   JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
   poolConfig.setMaxIdle(30);
   poolConfig.setMinIdle(10);
   poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(2000);
   jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, RedisDBUrl, port, 100);
   ```

   Let me know if above configuration will do the job. I am setting read timeout to 100ms and maxwait to 2000ms.
2. Let me know if my understanding is correct.

   At times I get  JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: **Read timed out**  or sometimes **connect timeout**.

   Here connect time out is thrown when my application is not able to make connection to redis withing configured time?

   Secondly, read timeout comes when application is connected to redis but operations(get/set) are taking time or for some reason?

   Lastly, how do i configure timeout for read timeout and connect timeout?

Answer (score 0):

After many hit and trial and some test runs found out, you can not set separate timeout for jedis get and set operations. 
May be you can use some external library to achieve(Like google's SimpleTimeLimiter.

Further from what I have observed connect timeout occurs when jedis tries to connect to redis server. In my case my redis server latency from my system is ~120-125ms so if I set timeout=100ms in jedis constructor I get "connect time out".

Whereas "read time out" comes when you are connected to redis server but redis operation doesn't return in specified time. To test this scenario I have set the timeout in constructor to 180ms and tried to run the flushall operation(takes long time), here I got read timeout.

Still not sure though whats the significance of poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis().

Comment: 'poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis()' is the maximum waiting time to get a resource from the jedispool, after which 'jedispool.getResource()' will give 'connection timeout' exception.